# Rearrange odd and even numbers

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, divide-and-conquer

Is there an O(n) algorithm to rearrange odd and even numbers preserving the order?  Auxiliary arrays may be used for intermediate results but the rearrangement should be done within array.

I found this http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/segregate-even-and-odd-numbers/ to do what is required but it does not maintain the order

```
Input:
1 4 3 8 6 5 7

Output:
1 3 5 7 4 8 6
```

Comment: is the input always sorted? if it's not, then there's no way it could ever be done O(n)

Comment: Why are you asking "*is there...*"? Do you know there is one? Do you need one?

Comment: Is the number sequence arbitrary? If so then reflect that in your example because the way you put it is confusing the readers.

Comment: Yes, the number sequence is arbitrary. I wanted to know if there is a way to do it in a two pass algorithm or so. Since overall complexity would still be O(n). Auxiliary arrays may be used for intermediate results but the rearrangement should be done within array

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

1. Create two doubly linked lists (or something that has O(1) concatenation) to store odd and even numbers separately.
2. Iterate over the input list, separate them to the lists on step1.
3. Concatenate two lists.

Comment: Your 3rd step should be "fill the array from the contents of the lists". But really linked lists are a pain to work with if you don't have to...

Comment: @Amit , I guess it depends; I find linked data structures easier to reason about. It also depends on the programming language, a purely functional language such as Haskell might favor linked lists instead of arrays.

Comment: I assumed the question is about arrays (input & output), but actually it doesn't say anything about it. It does say (now, after edit) no auxiliary array so I guess this means your answer isn't valid either. However, with linked lists, you don't need any auxiliary structures, just move items to the right place. It's *O(n)*.

Comment: @Amit, right, if the question requires arrays, my answer has an extra O(n) memory requirement, instead of O(1) with linked lists. But it's still O(n) time complexity.